# Как настроить размер кнопок в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я создал кнопку в Unity, настроил её размер, но ,после нажатия кнопки Play, размер кнопки уменьшился. Что мне делать?

Comment: Увеличить размер кнопки...

Comment: Вы настроили её в окне Scene, посмотрите как она выглядит в окне Game, и используйте адаптацию под разные экраны, изучите использование Canvas

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно адаптировать все элементы канваса под разные экраны[image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Якоря показаны в виде четырех небольших треугольных маркеров в представлении сцены - именно они отвечают за это. Изучите использование [Canvas](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/UIBasicLayout.html) в Unity.